# duplicated sessionkey

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, runtime, validator, networking

In `polkadot.js` staking , when i put the session key, the result is  "duplicated session key"

I use the command in SSH "echo `'{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"author_rotateKeys","params":[]}' | websocket -n1 -B 99999999 ws://127.0.0.1:9944"`

I run 2 nodes with different server, I already erase the node and start new node with different server, so I wanted change the session key but it does not work. duplicated session key again and again

what is the problem??

Comment: are you putting the same session key in both nodes?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you properly cleaned the database? Make sure to stop all nodes and clean their respective databases. If you stop-clean-start each node individually, the new database will immediately sync with the data from the old node.
2. There is no need to set this again if you have already set the keys in genesis.
3. Did you accidentally send multiple `set_keys` extrinsics?

Comment: quite a messy.. i gotta clrean and start new~ thanks~ i will try it again~

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is sent if chain is not synced yet making it freaking confusing. I have now created container with polkadot service 3 times ad each time tehre is already duplicate of the key when I first tiem rotate it... there also is no way to search where this duiplicate exists..